# Split a variable in windows into multiple parms

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop, input

I'm trying to take a single variable that has multiple words lets say PARM1 is sent as "my parm". I was attempting to use `FOR` to strip the Parm into two separate variables.

```
FOR /F "tokens= 1,2 delims= " %%I IN ('%~1') DO (SET FOLD=%%I)& (SET ODT=%%J)
```

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: is this batch? add the tag `batch-file` to your question if that is the case so you get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works:

```
set PARAM1=my param

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ("%PARAM1%") do (
    set FOLD=%%i
    set ODT=%%j
)

' Test variables
echo FOLD=%FOLD%
echo ODT=%ODT%
```

Comment: Worked like a charm and I see where I messed up, thank you for your help.